# Google Dialogflow Output contexts lifespan

Tags: dialogflow-es

Every time I add new output context in Google dialogflow it sets its lifespan to '5' 
I am following certain design pattern where I set output context lifespan to '1' only. Couldn't found any setting to change this behavior. 
Is there any other way to make output context default life span as '1'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, 5 is the API default, if you want something different you have to set it manually (it is not documented as the default anymore, but afair it used be and has been this way forever).